# Waiting for something to finsih, should I use thread.sleep or ReentrantLock?

Tags: java

I have a Java program. The logic is as follow:

1. place order out (relying on Interactive Broker / Binance API)
2. Once the order is filled (there will be a callback from the API), immediately execute a method called "calculateSomething"

The order is placed using Interactive Broker / Binance API. Once the order is filled, the API callback method will return a message.

The problem is that I do not know how to write out the code to identify that the order has been filled, so i can immediately execute the "calculateSomething" method with minimal waiting time.

I can think of two ways:

1. while loop and thread.sleep
2. `ReentrantLock`.

Method 1 works, but it's not instantaneous. Hence, I am exploring `ReentrantLock` and I am not sure the code is correct. Nonetheless, which method is the most efficient and can immediately execute the "calculateSomething" once the order is completed  If there is a more efficient approach, please give me some help, as I have been stuck in this problem for many days.

pseudocode below.

##### Method 1 - thread.sleep

```
placeOrder(); // place order to binance <- API method
while(order is not completed){
     Thread.sleep(1000)
     if(order is completed){
          return
     }
}
calculateSomething();
```

##### Method 2 - ReentrantLock

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
lock.lock();
System.out.println("1. Locked");
try {
     while(lock.isLocked()) {
          if(isOrderCompleted() == true){
               lock.unlock();
          }
     }
} catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
     if(lock.isLocked()) {
          lock.unlock();
     }
}
calculateSomething();
```

Comment: Both approaches are not ideal as the process won't resume if you application crashes. You also don't mention how to order is placed/completed (is it in the same process? or a different service?). Depending on the architecture you have, there are a few options that would make the solution reliable and run the calculation soon(ish) after the order has been completed.

Comment: it's all done within the same process. And order is placed using Interactive Broker's API and when the callback function will return a message when the order is filled. I am doing this on a normal desktop only.

Comment: By normal desktop do you mean an app? And what behaviour would you expect if the app closes while an order is being completed? Would the callback from the broker API retry if the call hasn't been acknowledged? I think you are posing this as a coding problem when you actually have a design/architecture issue.

Comment: Let’s assume the system doesn’t go down .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a blocking queue.

```
BlockingQueue<?> finishedOrders = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(512);
```

Then you have a loop that processes finished orders.

```
public void processFinishedOrders() throws InterruptedException{
    
    while(!Thread.interrupted()){
        finishedOrders.take();
        doSomethingRelevant();
    }
}
```

I would also suggest populating finishedOrders with a meaningful class.

```
BlockingQueue<Order> finishedOrders;

Order fin = finishedOrders.take();
doSomethingRelevant( fin );
```

That way the thread waiting on the api call can create a an order and add it to the finished orders queue, and the processing thread will have the relevant information.

Comment: Using a `Future` or `CompletableFuture`, or a `CompletionService` could also be an option.

Comment: This is still unreliable and doesn't address the problem of what happens if the system goes down half way through processing.

Comment: @Augusto if what system goes down? It doesn't really seem to be part of the question.

Comment: @matt  , thanks for the answer. So your suggestion is to create a new runnable class for `processedFinishedOrders()` method and keep the code where I put new order into the blockingqueue in the main class such that blocking queue will block the main class from executing further until the order is being processed fully. Only one new runnable class needs to be created, am i correct ?

Comment: I think you're mixing terms a bit. You would need a single thread that is executing `processedFinishedOrders()`. You could do this by creating a runnable and then either submitting it to an executor service or creating a new thread. Then you would have other threads (at least one other thread) that perform the ordering logic and add it to the queue. The thread waiting in `processedFinishedOrders()` method will start again if it was waiting. You talk about classes, but seem to be describing threads.

Comment: understood. Basically, there needs to be a producer and a consumer.

Comment: @user1769197 there doesn't need to be, but from the description of your problem it sounds like there could be. You could do what was suggested and use a Future. Submit the task to an executor, then poll the future until the task is complete.